# Algorithm suggestion to order data with specific condition

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, coding-theory, ordering, order-theory

Suppose, we want to rearrange all possible $n$-bit binary strings (i.e., we have $2^{n}-1$ possible strings) in a 1-D array $X$; given that stings with smaller [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) should be placed as much closely as possible. Is there any algorithm to find the best solution efficiently?

Note: I belive, for this problem, we need to maximize $\sum_\limits{i=0}^{2^{n}-2}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{2^{n}-1}\bigg(d(X[i],X[j]) \times |i-j|\bigg)$. Here, $d(X[i],X[j])$ is the hamming distance between $i$th and $j$th element of the array $X$.

Comment: Sounds hard to do. I'm not sure if it'll help you, but it sounds remotely similar to hierarchical clustering objectives (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05043.pdf). And also I don't think that the fact that your elements are binary strings will help you. I expect that at most you'll be able to get triangle inequality out of that fact.

Comment: BTW, from a practical point of view, some adaptation of average (or other) linkage may work well. Also the same function arises here: https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/12/8/162

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At least, now I have some clue!

Comment: What have you tried? How well does a random ordering do, in expectation? How well does a Gray code do? What can we find if we brute force the sum for very small n?